# How to prevent user from exiting an app when back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity, back

I have developed an app working successfully, but there are two activities, first is the splash screen and second one is webview. Now problem is that when back button is pressed it closes the App and exits, however the back, forward and refresh button are there in the app for internal navigation. So how to show an are you sure to exit dialog or to prevent user from deactivating the back key.

Answer (score 11):

Something like this by overriding `onBackPressed()` method of `Activity` class:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    MyActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do,

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

  //  super.onBackPressed();

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            // Setting Dialog Title
            alertDialog.setTitle("Exit alert");
             alertDialog.setMessage("Do You want Exit??");
            alertDialog .setIcon(R.drawable.galleryalart);


            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                          dialog.cancel();
                }
            });


            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             [youractivity].super.onBackPressed();


                }
            });


            alertDialog.show();



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackPressed in your activity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        super.onBackPressed();

                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SettingsActivity.this);

                // Setting Dialog Title
                alertDialog.setTitle("Signout your app");


                alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                              dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });


                alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                    }
                });


                alertDialog.show();



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        int imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert;
        Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);

        builder.setTitle("Exit").setMessage("want to exit?").setIcon(image).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                finish();
            }
        }).setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.setCancelable(false);
        alert.show();

    }

}
```